# On google spreadsheets how to use only a certain value of a function that returns an array?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

If I have some function like this:

```
function returnAnArray() {
  return [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
}
```

On the spreadsheet if I use `=RETURNANARRAY()` it will fill 5 lines containing the values of the array. If I wanted to use only the first or n value of an array, what is the syntax that I need to use on spreadsheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function returnAnArray(index) {
   var arrayOfNums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
   return arrayOfNums[index];
}
```

Then just use the formula `=returnAnArray(validIndexInArray)`

**Update:**

I wanted to share a few other things that I discovered.

Perhaps sometimes with the same function you want to return an array or just one element of the array you can incorporate it like this:

```
function returnAnArray(index) {
   var arrayOfNums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

   // if true, return single element of array
   if (index != null || index != undefined)
     return arrayOfNums[index];

   // else, return whole array
   return arrayOfNums;
}
```

Using `=returnAnArray()` will return the whole array, while `=returnAnArray(index)` will return a single element in the array.

Alternatively you could use the built in formula INDEX like this: `=INDEX(returnAnArray(), index)`

This would give you the ability to also retrieve a single element from a two dimensional array, which could also be built into the custom function with an additional parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Use INDEX built-in function.

**Example**
In the cell `A2` write the item number that you want, then write the following formula in A3:

```
=INDEX(returnAnArray(),A2)
```